# Site Deletion Automation SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation

I want to delete a batch of sites  saved in a text file or excel file,  URLS requests are saved in the file and i need an automation for site deletion, like a workflow that execute locking down then backup then delete.

I cannot user designer or deploy any solution, I need a way to to be able to feed the file as input and get results shown on screen if possible on a web part, or a column that shows the list of site status.

I thought of using content editor web part to show different buttons and then pass a parameter which is the file name but I dont know how to pass parameters to CEWP?